# Show $\int_{E} \inf\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n d\mu \le \inf \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_n d\mu$ and the analogous for the superior limits.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I'm required to solve the following problem:

1. Let $(f_n) \subseteq M(X, S)$ and suppose there is $g \in M^+(X, S)$ such that $\int g d\mu < + \infty$ and $-g \le f_n$ almost everywhere in $E \in S$. Then,

$$\int_{E} \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} f_n d\mu \le \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_n d\mu$$

2. If there is $g \in M^+(X, S)$ with $\int g d \mu < +\infty$ such that $f_n \le -g$ almost everywhere in $E \in S$. Then,

$$\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n d\mu \le \int_E \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} f_n d \mu$$

Here, $M(X, S)$ denotes the class of measurable functions and $M^+(X, S)$ the sub-class of non-negative measurable functions.

The thing here, is that this problem is situated on a chapter of the Dominated Converge Theorem, while Fatou's Lemma is on the previous chapter, so it's supposed not to be used this Fatou's Lemma, which causes me uncertainty (furthermore, Fatou's Lemma does not admit explicitly the "almost anywhere" hypothesis, but it still make sense to use it).

So, I'm just looking for a proof verification. Where is what I've done:

1. Since $-g \le f_n$ almost everywhere in $E \in S$, $0 \le f_n + g \in M^+(X, S)$ almost everywhere in $E \in S$. By Fatou's Lemma,
   $$\int_{E} \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} (f_n + g) d\mu \le \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} (f_n + g) d\mu$$
   On one hand, we have that
   $$\int_{E} \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} (f_n + g) d\mu = \int_{E} \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} f_n d\mu + \int_{E} g d\mu$$
   On the other hand, we have that
   $$\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} (f_n + g) d\mu = \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_n d\mu + \int_{E} g d\mu$$
   Since $\int_{E} g d\mu \le \int g d\mu < + \infty$,
   $$\int_{E} \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} f_n d\mu \le \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_n d\mu$$
2. Since $f_n \le -g$ almost everywhere in $E \in S$, $0 \le - g - f_n \in M^+(X, S)$ almost everywhere in $E \in S$. Again, by Fatou's Lemma,
   $$\int_{E} \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} (-g - f_n) d\mu \le \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} (-g - f_n) d\mu$$
   On one hand, we have that
   $$\int_{E} \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} (-g - f_n) d\mu = -\int_{E} g d\mu - \int_{E} \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} f_n d\mu$$
   On the other hand, we have that
   $$\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} (-g - f_n) d\mu = - \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_n d\mu - \int_{E} g d\mu$$
   Since $\int_{E} g d\mu \le \int g d\mu < + \infty$,
   $$\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n d\mu \le \int_E \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} f_n d \mu$$

Comment: Presumably you mean $\liminf_{n\to\infty}$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty)$?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes! My bad, I use to denote it $\overline{\lim}$ and $\underline{\lim}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis that $g$ is positive is irrelevant and the signs $-g$ and $+g$ are always irrelevant, I think. E.g. assuming $f_n\le g$ for all $n$ and some integrable $g$ is good enough for the supremum case, and assuming $f_n\ge g$ for all $n$ and some integrable $g$ is good enough for the infimum case.

Your work looks correct to me and is also very familiar - these manipulations are exactly what one requires in order to derive the (generalised) DCT given the Fatou lemma, and are standard.

In case you haven't seen one before, if you drop the integrability of $g$ as a hypothesis you get counterexamples such as: $f_n:=-\chi_{[n,\infty)}$, over the measure space $\Bbb R$, tends pointwise everywhere to zero (so, in particular $\liminf_nf_n\equiv0$) yet their integrals are constantly equal to $-\infty$, and $0<-\infty$ is quite false. This is essentially just a cautionary tale for why the monotone convergence theorem / Fatou's lemma really does require some nonnegativity assumption (my $f_n$ are also an increasing sequence of functions!).